# Generate numbered forms in Word where the number is shown twice

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to make Word generate a piece of text (with tables) n number of times and have it include the number in each piece of text twice?

I have tried using the sequence field, but then I can't get the number in there twice:

[image]

I need both top numbers to be "1" in this case, but in a next rendering it should be 2, then 3, etc.

As you can see, I'm trying to generate order forms for a local event (I simplified the layout a bit here).

Ideally, I could tell Word to give me 100 of this forms, and it would render them all, numbered. Or if I could just copy-paste the block, and have Word increase both numbers on every paste. Or paste the block and then update the sequence, but currently I can't find a way of duplicating the number.

Is this even possible in Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second SEQ field for the form (ie currently showing as 2 in your diagram above), add the switch \c (which is the preceding number in sequence, in this case your first SEQ field for each form).  You may need to select all and update fields after you copy and paste.